# What are the achievements for Zoombinis, and how do I get them?

Tags: zoombinis

When the game was re-released, there was a list of achievements added as well. However, in the game, there is only a list of "achievements" (presumably ones already earned), with no indication of what they are or how to get them, or even how many there are.

[image]

Does anyone know what these achievements are or how to get them?

Comment: I was not even aware that this game was re-released today...+1.  It's possible they're not implemented yet, and will be added (along with Steam Achievements) in the future.

Comment: @Zibbobz, turns out they have been released, I just received 2, for guiding 3 groups of Zoombinis through 2 separate parts of the game on a certain difficulty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, these acheivements are generally based upon game completion:

- Guiding 3 groups of Zoombinis through each section of the game on each difficulty
- Doing so without losing Zoombinis
- Bringing all the Zoombinis to the end (Completing the game)

However there are a few "extra" achievements, so far I have only found two - both of which are finding all of the "surprises" at each campsite.